# test case issue

Tags: java

hi
  I have one class,and in that class I have one method as follows:
  I am using java.

```
public class ABC{
    some code here...
     ..................
     PreparedStatement pre;
      public void insertUser(String firstName,String lastName){
          pre.setString(1,firstName);
          pre.setString(2,lastName);
          pre.execute();
      }
}
```

for above method I want to write the test case,I have created the test class as follows:

```
public class ABCTest{
    ABC abc=new ABC();
   public void testInsertUser(){
```

now here I want to write the assert statement,I want test whether insert is successful,
  I want to test the method variable using `assert()`. Please tell me how to write test case for this in java.

Comment: To the right when you were asking your question there was this handy **How to Format** box. Worth a read, as is [the page linked](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) from the **[?]** just above the question area. The more effort you put into your question, the better the quality and quantity of answers you'll receive. If **none** of your 11 other questions has really received an acceptable answer, with respect, it indicates a problem with the quality of the questions. The StackOverflow community is more helpful than that.

Comment: Note that you probably don't want your unit-tests, to assert.  Rather, you probably just want to return a `boolean`, so that your test framework can collect the results from multiple tests.

Comment: You asked the same quesition http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4895645/help-writing-junit-for-jdbc/4896904#4896904 .Avoid asking duplicate questions if you want you can edit your question to add more data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

do you mean something like:

```
public void testInsertUser(){
ABC.insertUser(User.firstname, user.lastname);
Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT firstname_Colname, lastname_Colname FROM Your_Table");
boolean found = false;
while (rs.next())
{
  found = ((User.firstname = rs.getString("firstname_Colname")) and (User.lastname = rs.getString("lastname_Colname")));
  if (found)
  {
    break;
  }     
}
assertEquals('test failed!', true, found);
}
```

if yes you are actually testing the PreparedStatement which doesnt make any sense for me!

Answer (score 1):

You need to do something like these:

1. Check the count of rows before and after the INSERT and assert that the after count is one greater than the before count.
2. Do a SELECT and see if your row made it into the database.
3. Check the number of rows affected that is returned by the call and see that it equals one.

Answer (score 1):

probably you have along with your 'insertUser' method other methods like 'selectUser' and 'removeUser' so in your testCase you should use 'selectUser' method to be sure that your user appear in DB, also in the end you should call 'removeUser' cause after the tests you should keep your data clean as it was before (for tests to be able to run multiple times on same test data with same results).